# Sass control directives to add attribute to elements with existing attribute

Tags: css, sass

I'm referring to the documentation here:

[sass  docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_9)

and trying to see if its possible to use an if statement to apply a letter spacing attribute to each class that uses a certain font family.

I've tried

```
h1 {
  @if font-family == 'Open Sans Condensed' {letter-spacing: 0.1em;}
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}
```

with the hope of outputting:

```
h1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
```

which doesn't work. i'm pretty sure that I'm approaching this problem from the wrong angle. Can anybody verify if this kind of usage is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways you could approach this:

1) Include the letter-spacing as part of the font-face definition.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  src: [urls for various formats go here];
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
 }
```

If you're loading the font in from an external stylesheet, like with google fonts or similar, you should still be able to declare a second `font-face` block that just includes the font-family and letter-spacing rules.

2) Use a sass mixin. You can make it very simple or more flexible, depending on whether you want to account for multiple fonts.

Basic one-font setup:

```
@mixin font-styles() {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

h1 {
  @include font-styles;
}
```

Or parameterized for multiple font styles:

```
@mixin font-styles($font: 'headings') {
   @if $font == 'headings' {
     font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
     letter-spacing: 0.1em;
   }
   @elseif $font == 'text' {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      [related font styles go here]
   }
   [add more font style sets as needed]
}

h1 { @include font-styles('headings'); }
p { @include font-styles('text'); }
```